# Unrecognized option or bad format `--writeModel' with command line

Tags: minizinc

Just want to write .mzn to .mps , with following the command-line:

**minizinc --writeModel test.mps test.mzn**

but the error comming :

**minizinc: Unrecognized option or bad format `--writeModel'**

minizinc: MiniZinc driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solver specific option for the MIP solvers included in MiniZinc. It should work by adding `minizinc --solver cbc --writeModel test.mps test.mzn`.